# Выводит несколько массивов вместо одного

Tags: php, массивы, yii2, foreach

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.
Есть у меня чемпионаты - пользователи добавили видео, из них сформировались версусы по два человека, по завершению нужно взять видео победителей и сформировать из них еще версусы и так до последнего победителя. Вот на моменте выборки победителей  возникла проблема.
Контроллер:

```
public function actionVersusManager()
{
$championships = CCompetition::find()->all(); // беру все чемпионаты
foreach ($championships as $champ) {
    $versuses = CVersus::find()->where(['poll_id' => $champ->id])->all(); // беру версусы принадлежащие чемпионату
    foreach ($versuses as $versus) {
        $options = COption::find()->where(['user_id' => $versus->winner])->andWhere(['poll_id' => $champ->id])->all(); // беру победителей из таблицы с видео
        if (!empty($options)) {
            $result = [];
            foreach ($options as $value) { // перебираю массивы, привожу в нужный вид
                $result = $value;
            }
            $new_options[] = $result;
            var_dump($new_options);
        }
    }
}
```

На том моменте, где выбираются видео победителей, `$options` возвращает 4 отдельных массива с нужными данными:

```
array(1) {
[0]=> тут даные 1
}
array(1) {
[0]=> тут даные 2
}
array(1) {
[0]=> тут даные 3
}
array(1) {
[0]=> тут даные 4
}
```

Мне нужно собрать их в один, такого вида:

```
array(4) {
[0]=> тут даные 1
[1]=> тут даные 2
[2]=> тут даные 3
[3]=> тут даные 4
}
```

Вроде как собрал, но `var_dump($new_options)` показывает снова 4 массива следующего вида:

```
array(1) {
[0]=> тут даные 1
}
array(2) {
[0]=> тут даные 1
[1]=> тут даные 2
}
array(3) {
[0]=> тут даные 1
[1]=> тут даные 2
[2]=> тут даные 3
}
array(4) {
[0]=> тут даные 1
[1]=> тут даные 2
[2]=> тут даные 3
[3]=> тут даные 4
}
```

Из них мне нужен только последний. Скажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выводите дамп `var_dump($new_options);` в теле цикла, соответственно он и выводит вам каждую итерацию. На самом же деле `$new_options` содержит нужный вам массив.

P.S.: от запросов в БД в цикле желательно избавляться.

Comment: вынес вывод за цикл `foreach ($championships as $champ) { }` вывело нужный массив. И код который версусы делает, тоже нужно было за него вынести, теперь нормально все. Спасибо!  
И еще, по поводу избавления от запросов в цикле, это для того что бы если нужно будет запросить много данных не кушало ресурсы?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял как должно выглядеть всё, но попробуйте вот такой вариант:

```
$versuses = CVersus::find()->where(['poll_id' => $champ->id])->all(); // беру версусы принадлежащие чемпионату
foreach ($versuses as $versus) {
    $options = COption::find()->where(['user_id' => $versus->winner])->andWhere(['poll_id' => $champ->id])->all(); // беру победителей из таблицы с видео
    $new_options = [];
    if (!empty($options)) {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($options as $value) { // перебираю массивы, привожу в нужный вид
            $result[] = $value;
        }
        $new_options[] = $result;
    }
    var_dump($new_options);
}
```